# Mongo: Quick way to find the last n inserts into a collection

Tags: mongodb

I am running a query like the following:

```
db.sales.find({location: "LLLA", 
               created_at: {$gt: ISODate('2012-07-27T00:00:00Z')}}).
         sort({created_at: -1}).limit(3)
```

This query is working as expected, but its not performing fast enough. I have an index on the location field, and a separate index on the created_at field. Please let me know if you see me missing something obvious here to make it faster.

Thanks for your time on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo won't use two indexes for a given query, if you want filter by `location` and sort by `created_at` you can add a compound index:

```
db.sales.ensureIndex({location: 1, created_at: -1})
```

You should run `explain` on your queries when you have issues like that. Sort in particular causes non-intuitive complications with indexing, and the `explain` command can occasionally make it obvious why.

It's also worth noting that you can usually sort by `_id` to approximate insert time (assuming auto generated `ObjectId` values), but that won't help you as much as a compound index will in this case since you're filtering on an additional field.

Answer (score 0):

just use IDs:

```
db.sales.find({location: "LLLA"}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(3)
```